# Is there a way to get all tagged AWS resources using AWS Ruby SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to get a list of all resources tagged with a specific value. 
Tag Name="Environment" Value="Foo"

Is there a way of doing this using 1 api call? Currently i can filter based on a tag, but i seem to need to execute this for all available services.

Is there a way to get all resources in 1 call like instances, security groups etc.. ?